# Differential of a smooth map definition in differential geometry.

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, definition

let $\mathcal{S},\mathcal{\tilde{S}}$  be two surfaces, and let $f$ be a smooth map:
$$
f:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathcal{\tilde{S}}.
$$
If $p\in\mathcal{S}$ and $\tilde{p}\in\mathcal{\tilde{S}}$, then the derivative $D_p$ of $f$ is defined as a map:

$$
D_p f : T_p \mathcal{S} \to T_{f(p)}\mathcal{\tilde{S}}.
$$

Specifically the Gauss map is a map that goes from $\mathcal{S}$ to $S^2$ (the unitary sphere). And the Weingarten map is defined as

$$
\mathcal{W}_{p,\mathcal{S}} = -D_p\mathcal{G}
$$

My question is... since there's a definition of derivative, what's the definition of differential? And how can we express the differential of $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: It depends what you mean by differential. Some authors call the derivative of $f$ as the differential of $f$, but I suppose this is not what you want. Do you mean the symbols like $dx,dy,dx\wedge dy$?

Comment: The map $D_pf$ that you've defined is typically called the differential and serves as a push forward.

Comment: @edm yes, essentially what could be the meaning of the symbols like $df$ in this case, also because $f$ is evaulated in some point $p \in \mathcal{S}$, and $p$ is given by the parametrization $\sigma(u,v)$ then what is the meanining of $d(f(\sigma(u,v))$? Something like that.

Comment: @gian, there's the further problem I didn't actually understood how to compute a derivative. Take for example a surface $\mathcal{S}$ and the gauss map $\mathcal{G}$ which maps every point $p\in \mathcal{S}$ into its normal. In practice how is the derivative computed? Say $\mathcal{S}$ is an ellipsoid for example, what's the derivative in a given point $p$? It's not a vector, it's a function that's all I know.

Comment: There are different definitions of the tangent vector. The most intuitive for me is to first specify a curve $C$ on $\mathcal{S}$ that runs through the point $p$. To compute the tangent vector to this curve, use a chart map $(U, \phi)$ that maps the region in question to the Euclidean space. Is it self explanatory from there?

Comment: @gian A complete example would be better...

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked for a more in-depth explanation of tangent vectors, although it is a slight digression from the original question. However, I cannot fit an explanation in comments. Hence the answer.

Let $\phi: I \rightarrow M$ be a curve parameterized by some interval such that $x = \phi(0)$. $x \in M$ is the point we are interested in. There is some chart $(U, \psi)$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \subset M$. There is no notion of derivative on a bare manifold, and thus we need to make use of $\psi$. Specifically, we are interested in the map $\psi \circ \phi: I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$. Now we do have a well-defined notion of tangent vector with the map $\psi \circ \phi$ which corresponds to the notion of $\mathbf{T}$ that you learned in multivariable calculus.

The tangent vector at $x$ is then $\frac{d}{dt} \psi \circ \phi$ evaluated at $\psi(\phi(0))$. The tangent space $T_xM$ arises when you consider all possible curves through $x$, at all possible parameterizations of those curves.

[image]